# How to use background execute in bashrc with alias?

Tags: shell

I want to replace complex commands with simple characters and execute in background, so I can shut down the terminal.

The command is `nWave -ssf test.fsdb(fsdb is a wavefile)`. In bashrc, I write `alias nwave='nWave -ssf'`.

If I want the command to be executed in background, I use `nWave -ssf test.fsdb &`. How to realize this command when using `alias` in bashrc file.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to close the terminal, you probably want to wrap the command in `nohup`. However, using 'nohup alias ...' will not work - as nohup only accept regular command. You can embed the nohup into the alias explicitly.

```
# In bashrc
alias bgnwave 'nohup nWave -ssf'

# At the terminal
bgnware test.fsdb &
```

As an alternative to bash `alias`, consider using bash function

```
function bgwnwave {
    nohup nWave -ssf "$@" &
}
```

Comment: In cshell, `nWave -ssf test.fsdb` can be replaced by `alias nwave "nWave -ssf \!*&"`, the above command cannot be implemented in bash.